# read request to smart contract without ABI

Tags: solidity, nft

I'm creating a collection of NFTs and I want to allow owners of NFTs from a contract that I don't own (e.g cryptokitties contract) to have special access to a page.
According to the documents, it's impossible to read from a contract without having the contract's ABI, but I don't have access to it.

Is there a workaround for reading data from the contract same as I would do directly from etherscan?

Answer (score 0):

`cryptokitties` is just an NFT, so it is an ERC721, and so you can find the ABI online (for example from [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol))

Just as a note, the ABI is just the interface, you don't need the implementation

Comment: They use the openzepplin as a base contract, but they did add multiple read functions that do not exist in the ERC721 implementation, so if I use the openzeppelin contract I should be able to only get access to the functions that were used in the CK contract?

Comment: @Soragim yes, you are able to access only to ERC721 methods... for the others, you can extend ERC721 methods with the other, but you will have to manually add them